# Astrojs Pagination `getStaticPaths()` route pattern was matched, but no matching static path was found for requested path

Tags: pagination, astrojs, dynamic-routing

I am writing a simple Astro blog application
My structure is like
[lang] [chapter] [page]
route is like. en/tasmania/things-to-do.mdx or hi/nsw/currentfestivals.mdx

I'm getting an error when trying to use paginate

``getStaticPaths() `route pattern was matched, but no matching static path was found for requested path`

```
`export async function getStaticPaths({paginate}) {
    const pages = await getCollection("places");


    const paths = pages.map((paged) => {
        const [lang, chapter,page] = paged.slug.split("/");
        return paginate( pages,{
            params: { lang, chapter, page},
            props: paged,
        });
    });

    return paths;
}`
```

However, without paginate, the code works fine

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const pages = await getCollection("places");


    const paths = pages.map((page) => {
        const [lang, chapter, place] = page.slug.split("/");
        return {
            params: { lang, chapter, place},
            props: page,
        };
    });

    return paths;
}
```

I'm trying to use pagination so that I can enable <=Previous and Next=> in my blog.
Any suggestions will be great.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to try solve with the method you're using to generate the params. But if it helps, you can look at my pagination, which is working. You could achieve the same result directly, if you were prepared to put 'lang', 'chapter' and 'place' in your frontmatter of each post.

https://github.com/tjex/tjex.net/blob/56db3474b48ac066f791367384bc8f629b368c24/src/pages/blog/%5B...page%5D.astro